# What is the 'true' argument in session->getBeforeAuthUrl(true)?

Tags: session, customer-session

What is the 'true' argument in session->getBeforeAuthUrl(true)?

I see some cases where it is

`$session->getBeforeAuthUrl(true)`

and some

`$session->getBeforeAuthUrl()`

What's the difference?  Almost impossible to google for this question and I don't see any getters in the Customer/Model/Session.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$session->getBeforeAuthUrl(true)` gives you the value for `before_auth_url` and deletes it from the session right after that. For reference see `Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien::getData()`. If you call the same method without `true`, you simply get the data value, but this will stay in the session for further use.

Comment: ah, so it's like a `consume` flag, nice.